# Формы глаголов, омонимичные словам других частей речи

Tags: омонимы, части-речи, глаголы

В выражении "Бог весть что" слово "весть"/"вѣсть" значит "знает", являясь формой 3 л. ед. ч. глагола "вѣдѣти" ("знать"). В то же время "весть" — это существительное, означающее "уведомление" и пр.

Какие ещё подобные примеры, в том числе из церковно-славянского/старославянского языка, Вы можете привести?

P.S. Про "печь", "честь", "мочь" не надо :)

Comment: "Стать", например.  Придут в голову другие, добавлю.

Comment: "Жил" (глагол и сущ. в род. падеже мн. числа).

Comment: Впрочем, Вам, по-видимому, нужны слова, которые не только омонимичны, но и могли бы использоваться в предложении, давая некое двоякое прочтение...

Comment: "Спас" ещё вот.

Comment: @VictorBazarov, на самом деле, меня интересуют слова с необычными личными формами (например про "весть" современный русскоязычный и не подумает, что это ВООБЩЕ может быть глаголом, разве что инфинитивом), но и в целом тема занятная.

Comment: У Гоголя, кажется, в эпиграфе к "Мёртвым Душам": "лаяй" - "лающее" (чудище)... Порыть у поэтов XVIII века (Державин, Ломоносов), наверное, можно найти что-нибудь.

Comment: Самые необычные личные формы у глагола быть : он есть, они суть. http://enc-dic.com/whistory/Sut-807/

Comment: Я был не прав - это у Радищева, к "Путешествию из Петербурга в Москву"...

Comment: @ДерзкийGrantum, с необычностью согласен, но это дело известное.

Comment: @VictorBazarov, про чудище, которое "обло, озорно, огромно, стозеевно и ла́яй" знаю, спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Формы глаголов, омонимичные словам других частей речи

[выть](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/152591)

[есть](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/161934)

[пасть](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/209024)

Плюс [отсюда](http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200700515):

Иногда одно и то же слово можно понять и как существительное, и как глагол. Например: ***день*** (день недели, день это куда-нибудь).

Все перечисленные ниже слова, кроме одного, обладают таким же свойством.
*(А) **гладь**; (Б) **рань**; (В) **три**; (Г) **лишай**; (Д) **попугай**.*

Все данные слова можно понять как глаголы в повелительном наклонении: *гладь (от гладить), рань (от ранить), три (от тереть), лишай (от лишать), попугай (от попугать).* Четыре слова можно воспринять и как существительные: *гладь, рань, лишай, попугай.* Слово *три* тоже имеет второй смысл, если обозначает число, но в этом случае оно является числительным, а не существительным.

==========

***шила, мыла, дела*** – формы существительных ср. рода *шило, мыло, дело;* формы глаголов *шить, мыть, деть;*
***были*** – форма существительного *быль*; форма глагола *быть*;
***жил*** – форма существительного *жила*; форма глагола *жить*;

==========

слово ***рой*** может быть и формой глагола *рыть* в повелительном наклонении, и им. п. ед. ч. существительного *рой,*

слово ***мой*** — и формой повелительного наклонения от глагола *мыть*, и им. п. ед. ч. м.р. местоимения *мой,*

слово ***вой*** — формой повелительного наклонения от глагола *выть* и им. п. ед. ч. существительного *вой,*

слово ***раскрой*** — формой повелительного наклонения от глагола *раскрыть* и им. п. ед. ч. существительного *раскрой.*

==========

Среди форм единственного числа существительного ***клей*** есть, в частности, такие: *1) клей; 2) клея; 3) клею.*

Форма *клей* также является повелительным наклонением глагола *клеить*, *клея* — деепричастием, а *клею* — формой первого лица ед. числа наст. времени того же глагола.

======================================================

======================================================

ПЛЮС из словаря Зализняка:

***упокой, запой, напой, перепой, пропой, спой, крой, закрой, перекрой, покрой, строй, настрой,  постой...***

***гною, слою, прослою, расслою, настою...***

===========================================================

===========================================================

ПЛЮС из Виноградова ("О грамматической омонимии в современном русском языке"): ***припёк, выгреб, изверг, постриг, навык, запах, волок, било, точило, зубрило, жало, крыло, пекло, начало, воротила, громила, надувала, объедала, вышибала…***

См.:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]